# Add "vc_add_shortcode_param" in WordPress functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress

I have migrated a WordPress website from one host to another. After migrating and configuring the database, I got lot of error. I have fixed a fair amount of them but I am unable to figure this error out:

Notice : add_shortcode_param has been deprecated since version 4.4. Use vc_add_shortcode_param instead. in /homepages/***/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3828

In my code from Line 3827-3845, there exists a function which is given below:

```
   function apache_mod_loaded($mod, $default = false) {
    global $is_apache;

    if ( !$is_apache )
        return false;

    if ( function_exists( 'apache_get_modules' ) ) {
        $mods = apache_get_modules();
        if ( in_array($mod, $mods) )
            return true;
    } elseif ( function_exists( 'phpinfo' ) && false === strpos( ini_get( 'disable_functions' ), 'phpinfo' ) ) {
            ob_start();
            phpinfo(8);
            $phpinfo = ob_get_clean();
            if ( false !== strpos($phpinfo, $mod) )
                return true;
    }
    return $default;
}
```

So, How can I use "vc_add_shortcode_param" here. Any kind of help will be appreciated a lot. Thanks

Comment: You have checked if have `<?Php wp_footer(); ?>` In the `footer.php` file?

Comment: Yes, wp_footer(); is there. Also the website was working perfectly on old hosting without any error.@Gislef

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem. The solution might seem a little strange but it worked. I created a new folder with all lowercase letters and linked my domain to that folder, moved all the files into that folder, edited wp-config.php and Voila!
P.S. The earlier folder name contained all uppercase alphabets.